# Qt form embedded in GUI results in shrinking to minimum size

Tags: forms, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qwidget

So I have this GUI .ui file made with Qt, which is embedded inside a sidebar on some Qt app I'm working on. Problem : it gets shrinked to an unsuable size.

My ui form starts with a QWidget, which is the main and base area for adding more things. This is set to be a grid layout (I didn't insert a grid layout manually, I just set the base QWidget to have one using the dedicated button at the top).

And it contains one thing only : a tab widget with all my stuff inside on two tabs.

And that's it.

Of course I did play with the size policy of everything, it's all set to Expanding and all.

This form is embedded by code into a larger tab widget. There is a new tab for every new form, I have like 10 different forms like this one.

Some actually have a QMainWindow at their base, and are not shrunk to death. I don't understand the difference, but I when I set my base thing to be a QWindow, the form does not shrink.

I also have one form in another tab that has a QWidget at its base and is not shrunk to death.

Any other information I could provide to help you guys help me ?

Comment: Could be just your margin size for internal layouts -- as in the child widget may be expecting it has a smaller size to fit than it should. layout->setMargin(0)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Would you mind expanding a little ?

Comment: Without seeing exactly the size I made an assumption of what it looked like, and I imagined a widget that had multiple layouts with a fixed margin size. This could squish everything to a small size, but only if the widget was a small size to begin with.

Comment: I don't understand the notion of fixed margin size. Margins are, AFAIK, properties of layouts, that just control the spacing left, right, top and bottom of it. They are an integer and are always fixed, in that sense. There is no "adapt" or "automatic" option or similar for margins. Just an integer.
But yes, my widget has multiple layouts.

Comment: I just meant fixed as in a specific, non-0 value. Many layouts will impose a default margin when not specifying one. When you say shrunk it sounded like you're expecting something to expand that is not, perhaps there's something preventing it from expanding such as a spacer?